# What is a 'Schema' in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

As the question clearly indicates, what is actually a Schema in PostgreSQL that I see in the top level of the hierarchy in pgAdmin(III)?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Comment: @zero323 Is it some kind of namespace like thing? I'm not understanding what the docs is saying

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I'm answering my own question just to clarify any other people (who do not have time to read docs or want a more simplified version):

You can think of a Schema as a namespace/package (just like in Java or C++). For example, let us assume `mydb` is the name of our database, `A` and `B` is the name of two different schemas which are present in the same database (`mdb`).

Now, we can use the same table name in two different schemas in the same single database:

```
mydb -> A -> myTable
mydb -> B -> myTable
```

Hope, that clarifies your answer. For more detail: [PostgreSQL 9.3.1 Documentation - 5.7. Schemas](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-schemas.html)